# css only affect for only first div

Tags: html, css, laravel

i have a problem for this case.

html code :

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-12 kotakartikelhome1">
   <div class="sentence">               
   </div>
</div>
```

css :

```
.kotakartikelhome1{
    background-image: url("img/artikelhome1.jpg");
    filter: brightness(50%);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
}
```

i just set for kotakartikelhome1 in filter for decrease the brightness, because i set it for my background image. then everything when i put anything inside sentence's class, everything getting dark, how to set those filter only affect the first div?

Comment: Try this, replace the filter with whatever you need: https://codepen.io/akademy/pen/FlkzB

Comment: why is not working on me?

 .kotakartikelhome1:before{
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;

  background-image: url('img/artikelhome1.jpg');
  filter: brightness(50%);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  height: 400px;
 }

Answer (score 2):

`filter` is a css property that affects the entire div, and thus anything inside it. So all child divs will also have that filter 'in front' of them.

If you just want to darken your background image, then I would suggest using a css3 gradient fallback.

`background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ), url('img/artikelhome1.jpg');`

This will give you a 50% opacity black overlay.

Comment: This solution does work.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```css
.kotakartikelhome1{
    background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/350x150);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    height: 400px;
    filter: brightness(50%);
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.sentence {
    color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-12">
  <div class="kotakartikelhome1"></div>
   <div class="sentence">        
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab architecto sit excepturi quod nam molestias! Sit deleniti odit harum repellendus quam molestiae, natus commodi sint accusantium animi eos, ad tempore!
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Put an id on the first element and add the styling to that.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-12 kotakartikelhome1" id="darken">
   <div class="sentence">               
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-12 kotakartikelhome1">
   <div class="sentence">               
   </div>
</div>

<style>
    .kotakartikelhome1{
        background-image: url("img/artikelhome1.jpg");
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        transition-duration: 0.5s;
        height: 400px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #darken{
        filter: brightness(50%);
    }

    .sentence{
        filter: brightness(100%);
    }
</style>
```

Comment: The container's children will still inherit the filter property.

Comment: Yes, That is how css works.  you will need to use different divs as above if you only want one to be affected.  You could overwrite the brightness in the sentence div again if you really want that behaviour. edited above